# Setting value of unchecked checkbox php

Tags: php, checkbox

I have this form

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="po[]" value="<?php echo $ord['id'] ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="acts[]" value="1" />
        <input id="acts" value='2' type="checkbox" <?php echo $check ?> name="acts[]" />
    </td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $pnme['icon'] ?>" style="height: 25px; width: 25px; vertical-align: middle;" /><?php echo $pnme['name'] ?></td>
    <td><input id="per" style="background: #BDBDBD; width: 100px;" name="per[]" size="5" type="text" class="small" value="<?php echo $ord['fee'] ?>" /></td>
    <td><input id="dol" style="background: #BDBDBD; width: 100px;" name="dol[]" size="5" type="text" class="small" value="<?php echo $ord['cost'] ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to get it to pass a different value if the checkbox is not checked, I have a `hidden` input but it does not pass the values correctly where I need it to, when the form posts this is how I handle the information

```
    $po = implode(",", $_POST['po']);
    $po = explode(",", $po);

    $fee = implode(",", $_POST['per']);
    $fee = explode(",", $fee);

    $co = implode(",", $_POST['dol']);
    $co = explode(",", $co);

    $act = implode(",", $_POST['acts']);
    $act = explode(",", $act);
    print_r($act);
    for ($i = 0; ; $i++) {
    if ($i > count($po) - 1) {
        break;
    }
```

for example if I check every box it sets the array like this

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 2 [8] => 1 [9] => 2 [10] => 1 [11] => 2 [12] => 1 [13] => 2 [14] => 1 [15] => 2 [16] => 1 [17] => 2 [18] => 1 [19] => 2 [20] => 1 [21] => 2 )
```

even though ever single one should have the value of 2

I added this trying to set the initial value to 1 thinking that if the box is checked it would overwrite the value, but this doesn't seem to be the case

I am not sure how to handle this situation and make it work with my processing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[]` array convention dynamically creates the next index, so if you have:

```
name="acts[]"
name="acts[]"
```

Then you get:

```
acts[0]
acts[1]
```

The hidden and checkbox inputs with the same name that need to hold the checked and unchecked value need to have the same index, so specify like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="acts[0]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="acts[0]" value="2" />

<!-- more checkboxes -->

<input type="hidden" name="acts[10]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="acts[10]" value="2" />
```

This will give you a `$_POST['acts']` array with 11 items, index 0-10 with the value either `1` or `2` depending on whether it was checked or not.

Also, I have no idea what you are doing with the `implode()` and `explode()`.  If you are just trying to reindex the numeric keys then use `array_values($_POST['acts'])`.

Comment: The only reason this won't work is because on submit I have like 11 indexes on the same name that is why I have it set the way I do, I don't think using the `hidden` input is what I am actually needing to do, I just don't know any other way of going about it

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, and pointing out my horrific use of over coding with `implode` and `explode` !!